# How to disable a particular device from waking a computer up from suspend?

Tags: usb, suspend, pci

I would like to disable waking from suspend when a mouse is moved.

I am aware of the file `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. I can disable one particular `pci` and thus disable a wakeup by the mouse. The problem is that this also disables wakeup by a keyboard which is not desired. Both the mouse and the keyboard are wireless devices with two separate wifi dongles connected to two different usb ports in the machine (no other usb ports available, so preferably the solution should work even when they are both plugged in one USB hub). When I run `lshw` I can see both devices listed under the same `pci` which seems to be the problem.

Is there anything that can be done to achieve this? Any other way how to disable a device from waking up the machine? I haven't found anything useful in the `BIOS`.

The system is Debian Bullseye with KDE desktop if it is of any importance.

Answer (score 0):

try using /sys/bus/usb/devices/<device_name>/power/wakeup instead

see https://community.frame.work/t/waking-immediately-from-suspend-or-hibernate-how-i-fixed-it-for-me/19763